# Add icon for App Store (required for all apps) to Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons, app-store

I am preparing to submit my application to the Apple App Store and have been researching the requirements for the App Icon. I have filled in all of the allotted slots shown in this picture from Apple's website [image]

However [the docs say that a 1024x1024 icon is required for the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) and I do not see any "slot" for that image in my Xcode project. Where and how do I add that required 1024 x 1024 app icon?

Answer (score 4):

Make a 1024x1024 icon and name it "iTunesArtwork@2x.png" add to assets catalogue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [makeappicon](http://makeappicon.com/) to generate an .xcassets catalogue... makes life easier

(I'm not affiliated with the above)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to log in to [Itunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) and then go to my apps and scroll down a bit to General App Information.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Asset Catalog as pictured in your example there is no 1024 icon.  Normally, for OS X apps the 512pt 2x is the 1024 x 1024 icon.  On iOS Apps you must upload a 1024 x 1024 image to iTunes Connect separately from your Asset Catalog that has no transparency.  On OSx apps it takes the image from your binary bundle that you uploaded.